# Azure Policy - Create a definition to force the tag name of "whatever' but the value must be in the format of YYYY-MMM-DD

Tags: azure, tags, policy

I've been battling on trying to create an Azure policy definition that would allow me to force a tag creation of "whatever", in my case, TTO (transition to operations), and i am trying to create a value for the tag that is forcing the user to enter the date in the format YYYY-MMM-DD. that equates to 2023-Jan-23 etc etc.

I've tried many things, even using ChatGPT to help since i'm not a coder, but i know the basics, but nothing seems to work. Everything I try ends up in either an error in the policy definition creation, or it takes the tag value as a "Literal" entry.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
            "match": "^[0-9]{4}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-[0-9]{2}$"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "tagName",
        "description": "Name of the tag to enforce"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

that was my latest attempt, but it is never taking the value field of the tag as a variable, but was literal.

I have a need to force the date as YYYY-MMM-DD for another policy that will append the tag based on the date. if it cannot parse the date, it cannot update the tag, therefore, i am trying to eliminate human error and make sure my mini project is fully automated.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks

I've tried using chatgpt for code assistance, but it is too stupid and provides more errors then anything and eventually loops me in a circle as it forgets the original request.

i've tried creating a initiative with the "require a tag and its value on resource group, and tried to create an initiative parameter, still no go.

I've tried writing different pieces of code, using array's vs strings, but nothing i can get to work.

I'm also steering away from ####-##-## (YYYY-MM-DD) as the first 12 days of month and day can get swapped and create another human error, therefore trying to stay within the range of YYYY-MMM-DD